# Unable to connect to wireless network thru alternate driver

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Windows 7 PC.
Am a complete newbie to the linux system.

I first created a bootable Ubuntu USB to try out the OS without installing and the wireless worked fine with it after using the additional driver for Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver from bcmwl-kernel-source.

However after installing Ubuntu from the bootable disk, I am no longer able to use this additional driver.
Every time I select the additional driver and apply changes, nothing happens, no logs, errors, nothing :( and it switches back to the previous selection.

Please help and let me know how can I get the wireless driver to work on the installed Ubuntu.

EDIT : Please any information how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did it ask you for your password?

Comment: yes it did but still it did not work eventually

Comment: Can you tell what does it say for the source? Is it something like `Install from bcmwl-kernel-source`?

Comment: No, it says the same thing as it does for the USB version,in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type this:

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

This worked for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Will this work without an internet connection ? Right now, since the wireless is not working, I do not have any internet connection on the ubuntu system

Comment: Of course not! Were you trying previously as well without an internet connection?

Comment: No,no...I think I was not clear in my question...actually earlier when i booted ubuntu directly from USB (without installing), i was able to activate the additional driver and connect to the internet. Now, after installing it, I am not able to activate the same driver in the installed version (so no Internet)... that is the actual problem, I can still boot directly from the USB and get the driver to work. The question is why the bcmwl-kernel-source additional driver is not getting activated in the installed version... I hope I could clarify the exact questionnow

Comment: Connect to the internet via Ethernet and try installing it using the command I gave you